# 401 (rest_comment_login_required) when posting comment on WordPress 4.7.0 with basic auth

Tags: wordpress, authentication

I'm trying to post a comment to WordPress (4.7.0) using basic authentication as described in the [documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/) and in [WP REST API: Setting Up and Using Basic Authentication](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/wp-rest-api-setting-up-and-using-basic-authentication--cms-24762).

However, I keep getting 401 errors back.

```
{"code":"rest_comment_login_required","message":"Sorry, you must be logged in to comment.","data":{"status":401}}
```

I activated the basic authentication plugin which then should turn this call into an authenticated call, right?

Comment: 401 error means that you have something wrong related with authentication in your script. If you can show your code it will be more easy to get solution for your case.

Comment: Assuming you refer to the client side script (not WP):
response = requests.post(
                    url=url,
                    data=data,
                    headers=headers,
                    auth=auth,
                )
Where auth is a tuple of (user, pass). I'm getting same results (401) when posting from advanced rest client, there i define an Authorization header field with the base encoded value.

Comment: I managed to get around this issue using a "hack" as described in https://www.contradodigital.com/2016/04/06/post-comments-wordpress-rest-api-version-2/#.WT53XIh96kA.

Notice version 4.8 has this same issue.

Answer (score 8):

You need to add a filter to your theme's functions.php file:

```
add_filter( 'rest_allow_anonymous_comments', function ( $allow_anonymous, $request ) {
    // ... custom logic here ...
    return true; // or false to prohibit anonymous comments via post
}, 10, 2 );
```

Documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/rest_allow_anonymous_comments/

Answer (score 0):

1. Go to your root WordPress folder like `rootfolder/wp-includes/rest-api/endpoints`
2. Open the file: `class-wp-rest-comments-controller.php`
3. Change the line:

   ```
   $allow_anonymous = apply_filters( 'rest_allow_anonymous_comments', false , $request );
   ```

   to

   ```
   $allow_anonymous = apply_filters( 'rest_allow_anonymous_comments', true, $request );
   ```

That's all

Comment: I don't think this answer is acceptable. One does not simply edit the core platform files